# Application that saves progress after closing

Tags: android

I'm new to android, and i don't know how to make an app that if you set things inside it it will save your progress once you close it.

for example, when use input's something into an EditText, like in a to-do list app, i want all the data of the app to be saved even after shutdown.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SharedPreferences http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Obtain them using [getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences%28android.content.Context%29)